# Java Slowdown on OSX 10.9

Tags: java, macos

Today I updated my MacBook Pro (Mid 2012 base model with RAM upgraded to 16GB) to OSX 10.9 Mavericks. I am currently developing a game based on the LWJGL and the last time I coded was ~20 minutes before starting the update. I was getting steady ~1300 FPS on my app.

After the update, I installed Java and tested the exact same .jar as before. To my surprise, the fps was ranging from 80 to 150 with really big fluctuations. After the first reboot, the fps started to range from 650 to 850, also fluctuating a lot. Even more surprising, my Windows 7 virtual machine (Parallels 9) is getting steady ~900 FPS.

That's my first OSX big update, since my Mac came with ML installed. Is it normal to experience problems with Java after such updates? Can I expect this to be fixed with Java/OSX updates? Also, may a clean OSX install fix it?

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest features of OSX Mavericks is the ability to cut down on battery life by putting applications to sleep and consolidating processes to reduce the amount of times the processor has to "wake up". They even coined the term "App Nap". I would imagine that your machine is just trying to save power under the new operating system designed for such.

http://www.apple.com/ca/osx/advanced-technologies/